# Spring: set "profile" attribute in a reference bean

Tags: java, spring

I am working on Java web services using Spring 3.2. There are two projects, A and B. In project A's appContext.xml, it tried to refer to a bean from project B's appContext.xml. However, the bean in project B has been encapsulated within different profiles for various deployment environments. The question is whether we could specify the profile in project A's referred bean?

appContext.xml in project A:

```
<bean id="beanA">
    <property name="locationsList">
        <list>
            <ref bean="beanBID">
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

appContext.xml in project B:

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="beanBID">
        <!-- stuff only for dev -->
    </bean>
</beans>
<beans profile="prod">
    <bean id="beanBID">
        <!-- stuff only for prod -->
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The compiler complains about `<ref bean="beanBID" profile="dev">`. Are there any alternatives to refer to a specific profile for `beanBID`? Thanks.

Comment: Nope as the use of profiles should be transparent for the usage of your application context. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: As  far as the said profile is active your bean should be available; as pointed out by @M.Deinum

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am trying to just load the "<!-- stuff only for dev -->" without modifying project B's appContext.xml. I know that I could use @ActiveProfiles("dev") in the Java code to refer to "<!-- stuff only for dev -->". But if I just need the dev profile from beanBID kinda of every places in project A, I really wish to specify the profile in project A's appContext.xml once instead of adding @ActiveProfiles("dev") everywhere. Is that doable?

Comment: `@ActiveProfiles` is for testing purposes only not for runtime code..

Comment: @M.Deinum OK. The project A's appContext.xml is actually for Unit Testing, so `<ref bean="beanBID" profile="dev">` could be a one place change for all the unit tests. Does it not supported in Spring 3.2?

Comment: Then I don't see the problem, as the bean is available in that context, just add `@ActiveProfiles` to your test class. Or just override the `BeanBID` in your test specific context and don't use profiles.

Comment: @M.Deinum What if the project A has tons of unit test files that need to update with `@ActiveProfiles`? Doesn't `<ref bean="beanBID" profile="dev">` be a much neater solution to allow you update at a single location without touching the rest of the code? I just want to see why such feature doesn't exist.

Comment: Because that goes against the whole purpose of profiles. You can put `@ActiveProfiles` on a super class and then it will be inherited. Or set it as a system parameter (`spring.profiles.active` property).